# Install Ubuntu OS on SSD and other files to HDD

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, system-installation

I am building a new PC. I am planning on having both a SSD and HDD.

I want to install the latest Ubuntu release to, and have the PC boot from and run the OS from, the SSD.

I also want any files, such as pictures, music, docs, etc to automatically be written to and saved on the HDD.

This will keep the SSD/OS relatively "clean" and allow for the fastest possible boot.

The forums here have a lot of posts about Dual booting Windows 7 and Ubuntu, moving a system over to SSD, cloning from HDD to SSD, etc. I cannot seem to find a post on this exact subject. If there is one, can somebody direct me to it.

Note that I am a noob when it comes to Linux. I have studied and understand how to do such an install and disk(s) setups on Windows 7 and Windows 8.

Comment: You haven't specified if you will also have any Windows version and if so which OS will be your primary system.

Comment: Sorry, failed to state this in original question: no, there will be no other OS on the box or any drives, just Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using Ubuntu on my Hybrid Hard Disk (SSD+HDD) for more than a year now, with the first SSD partition allocated for root filesystem (referred to as `/`) and second SSD partition allocated for `/home` (which includes all user settings and also  some basic user data) as well as a large data partition for the bulk of user data files and folders and a swap partition on the HDD.

And this seems a good configuration with a good performance for my purposes.